# Let $a_n=\cos(a_{n-1}), L=[a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...].$ Is there an $a_0$ such that $L$ is dense in$[-1,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been experimenting with recursive sequences lately and I've come up with this problem:

> Let  $a_n= \cos(a_{n-1})$ with $a_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ and $L=[a_1,a_2,...,a_n,...].$
>   
> Does there exist an $a_0$ such that $L$ is dense in $[-1,1]?$

I know of $3$ ways of examining whether a set is dense: 

$i)$The definition, that is, whether its closure is the set on which it is dense, in our case this means if: $\bar L=[-1,1]$. 

ii)$(\forall x \in [-1,1])(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists b \in L):|x-b|<\epsilon$

$iii)$ $(\forall x \in [-1,1])(\exists b_n \subseteq L):b_n\rightarrow 
x$

So far I haven't been able to use these to answer the question. I tried plugging in different values of $a_0$ and see where that leads but I have not found any corresponding promising "pattern" for $a_n$. Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: Neat question. A small comment: you can make your sequence $a_{n} = \cos(a_{n-1})$, since $\cos(x)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Edited as you suggested! Thanks again!

Comment: The main problem is:
$$a_0 \in \mathbb{R} \implies a_1 \in [-1,1] \implies a_2 \in [0.54,1].$$
Thus, this will never be dense in the whole interval.

Comment: @menag Thanks for your observation! So, should I look for a subset of $[-1,1]$ in which $L$ is dense?

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake if you look closely at my answer, you will have sufficient evidence to conduct a rigorous proof that L is not dense and can't be.

Comment: In the meantime, you can play with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(n)%3Dcos(f(n-1)),+f(1)%3D5, with various values for $f(1)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, if you study recursive sequences, then you probably heard about ["Lamere Ladder"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Bud_HAemxR8C&pg=PA318&lpg=PA318&dq=Lamere%20ladder&source=bl&ots=86YJxwbZFt&sig=HLADUXex5F9Y-ZQ_-XUet3KJ_-M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KZVEVe_KHY7KaL6CgIgN&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Lamere%20ladder&f=false).

According to Lamere Ladder for $\cos(x)$ (which is also a [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) because of [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)), this function has a [fixed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x)%3Dx) (stationary) point. So, regardless of $a_0$, $a_1$ will end in between $[-1, 1]$ and from there on, the sequence $\{a_n\}$ will tend to the fixed point of $\cos(x)$. Which makes $L$ a converging sequence, so $L$ can't be dense, because the only point satisfying ii) (in your question) is its limit.

On another note, [Kronecker's approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html) is quite an useful tool too. For example $\{n+ m \cdot 2 \cdot \pi \space | \space m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ is dense on $\mathbb{R}$ and $cos(x)$ is a continuous function, making $\{cos(n)\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ dense on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Anyway, could anyone explain why was this post downvoted? It's disappointing!

Comment: Small comment: One neat way to add hyperlinks is this: "[some text](some link)". It looks better than adding the link. For instance, if you write "$[$Kronecker's approximation theorem$]$(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html)" it will look like this: [Kronecker's approximation theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html). (pd: I didn't downvote you).

Comment: @NateRiver thank you for the advice, I fixed my answer! ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I am not formally-as part of a course-studying recursive functions, just checking some properties myself, so Lamere Ladder is not known to me. I am obviously aware of Banach's fixed point Theorem, but I have some difficulty understanding how it applies here. If you could answer in a more rigorous manner I would be obliged but in any case thank you for the usefull contribution!

Comment: Just read your comment-I guess I will try it myself after reading more about Lamere Ladder..

Comment: @rtybase You are welcome.

Comment: Banach's fixed point Theorem guarantees that sequence $\{a_n\}$ doesn't become periodic from some $n$ onwards. You will have to be careful around $x=\frac{\pi }{2}$ because $\left | \cos^{'}x \right |=\left | \sin x \right |=1$ in this point.

Answer (score 0):

By continuity of cosine function, $a_n=\cos a_{n-1}$, which for any $a_0\in [-1,1]$ satisfies $a_n>0$ for all $n=1,2,...$, so can not intersect the open set $[-1,0)-\{a_0\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your attempt, but in $[-1,1] \cos x$ is not increasing, $\sin x $ is..

Comment: No no .... I mean that the sequence is increasing....I.e. $a_0<a_1<....$

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot see why it is increasing there. Can you prove it please?

Comment: But why assume that $a_1>1?$ Say, for $a_0=2$, you have $a_1=\cos 2=-0,41<0 $

Comment: That is not allowed because you asked whether L is dense in [-1,1],  which makes sense only if L is a subset of [-1,1].

Comment: Still not sure about this, but I will simply set $L=[a_1,a_2,...,a_n]$ .