# Iteration converges $x_{n+1}=\cos x_n$ for any $x_0\in \Bbb R$

Tags: limits, numerical-methods

How do I prove that iteration $x_{n+1}=\cos x_n$ converges for any $x_0\in \Bbb R$ ?

Comment: use the fixed point theorem of Banach

Comment: There is a lot of duplicates, about 5 or so.

Comment: Come on folks, down votes without giving a comment what is wrong on christmas?

Comment: Yep, here is another duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701935/let-a-n-cosa-n-1-l-a-1-a-2-a-n-is-there-an-a-0-such-that-l/

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

WLOG, we can suppose $0\leq x_0\leq \pi$. then $\forall n\geq 2 \;\; |x_n|\leq 1$ and $\forall c\in[-1,1]\;| \sin(c)|\leq \sin(1)<1$.
thus, by MVT

$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\sin(1)|x_n-x_{n-1}|.$$

From here, you prove that $(x_n)$ is Cauchy and converges to the fixed point.

Comment: $x_0\in\Bbb R$ gives $x_1\in[-1,1]$ and $x_2\in[\cos 1,1]$, which gives a little, but insignificantly so, more information than what you wrote.