# value of $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(a_{n+2}-a_{n}\right)$ is

Tags: limits

> Let $a_{1}=a$ and $a_{n+1}=\cos(a_{n})\;\forall \;n\;\in \mathbb{N}.$
>
> Then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}(a_{n+2}-a_{n})$ is

Try: $a_{n+2}=\cos(a_{n+1})=\cos(\cos(a_{n}))=\cos(\cos(\cos (a_{n-1})))=\cdots \cdots \cos(\cos\cos\cos(\cdots \cdots \cos(a)))))))$

Did not know how can i solve it, could some help me , Thanks

Comment: Try to show that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$ exists, first (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701935/let-a-n-cosa-n-1-l-a-1-a-2-a-n-is-there-an-a-0-such-that-l/1702090#1702090)). Then the limit of the difference is the difference of the limits. Or the sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Apply Banach's fixed point theorem to $\varphi(x) = \cos(\cos(x))$.

Comment: Did not understand , Can you explain me.

Comment: @DXT What exactly did you not understand?

Comment: I mean Branch Fixed point Theorem

Comment: @DXT If you were given this exercise, I am sure you had Banach's fixed point theorem in class. You can read it up here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem ($T$ is $\varphi$ and $X$ is any sufficiently large interval here)

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

- $\cos: [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$
- $|\cos'(x)| = |\sin x| \leq \sin 1 < \frac{9}{10}\Rightarrow \cos$ is contractive on $[0,1]$
- $\Rightarrow$ $a_{n+1} = \cos a_n$ converges to the only fixpoint in $[0,1]$.

Now, reason why irrespective of the starting value $a$ the sequence $a_n$ will have to fall into $[0,1]$ "earlier or later".

Comment: $\cos{x}$ is $[-1,1]\rightarrow[-1,1]$.

Comment: @rtybase : $\cos (-1) = \cos 1 \in [0,1]$. So, my one is a bit "narrower".

Comment: Say initial condition is $a_0=3$, then $\cos(a_0)=-0.9899924...$. It's still fine to consider $\cos$ as a contraction mapping on $[-1,1]$, it has one fixed point anyway.

Comment: @rtybase In any case, for a sufficiently large $n$ (actually quite small), you have that $a_n\in[0,1]$.

Comment: @egreg I know. It's not me who should provide these details. And it's really easy to update the answer and close this little gap.

Comment: @rtybase : Maybe you didn't read the last sentence in my answer? There I write exactly this detail :-)